# Failure installing Anaconda

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I installed Anacaonda (in fact, I have installed, un-installed and re-installed many times without success).  I think, using the "cmd" command, after I have input "conda", I can see something which indicates Python has been installed successfully.  However, what I could see on screen was "Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py"''  How to fix this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall Anaconda and remove any related folders (e.g., C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3).

Download the latest Anaconda.

Install it to a short path without spaces, like C:\Anaconda3.

Adjust Environment Variables:
Search "Environment Variables" on your PC.
Edit the "Path" variable in "System Variables".
Add C:\Anaconda3 & C:\Anaconda3\Scripts.

Restart CMD and type conda --version.

should fix it :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).